# QGIS QtQuick integration?

Tags: qgis, qt, qml

I would like to use QGIS with QtQuick. I can use QGIS with QtWidget with the libs that I downloaded from OSGeo4W but there is no qtquick libraries in there. In QGIS's website there is a demo with QtQuick but since I don't have the qtquick libraries I can't use that code. Where can I found qgis quick libraries?

In demo's profile they write this but I don't have qgis_guick lib

```
  QGIS_PREFIX_PATH = $${QGIS_INSTALL_PATH}
  QGIS_LIB_DIR = $${QGIS_INSTALL_PATH}/lib
  QGIS_INCLUDE_DIR = $${QGIS_INSTALL_PATH}/include
  QGIS_QML_DIR = $${QGIS_INSTALL_PATH}/qml
  QT_LIBS_DIR = $$dirname(QMAKE_QMAKE)/../lib

  INCLUDEPATH += \
    $${QGIS_INCLUDE_DIR}/qgis \
    $${QGIS_INCLUDE_DIR}

  LIBS += -L$${QGIS_LIB_DIR}
  LIBS += -lqgis_core -lqgis_quick
```

Answer (score 2):

Base on QGIS Documentation ( https://qgis.org/api/qgsquick.html) it is neccessary to buile the library.

**Building the library**

The QGIS Quick library is not built by default because QGIS application currently does not use it. In order to build the library please make sure that `WITH_QUICK` variable in `CMake` configuration is set to `ON`.

It is recommended to build with `CMake` variable `ENABLE_TESTS` set to `ON` because that will also build a small example application that uses Qt Quick components. In the generated project you should see target "`qgis_quickapp`".

The built QML plugin is installed to a dedicated directory - see `QgsApplication::qmlImportPath()`. When using QGIS Quick components, it is necessary to either use `QQmlEngine::addImportPath()` to add that directory or to specify `QML2_IMPORT_PATH` environment variable.